# Param in URL not passed to a form - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, single-table-inheritance, sti

When accessing URL `localhost:3000/buyers/sign_up?email=abc%40abc.com` , the sign-up form is displayed but email field stays empty and is not auto-filled with abc@abc.com.
Could this be related to the implemented Single Table Inheritance (STI) ? -> Buyer inherits from User.

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users, :controller => {:sessions => 'sessions'}, :skip => :registrations do
    delete '/logout', :to => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get '/login', :to => 'sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post '/login', :to => 'sessions#create', :as => :new_user_session
  end

  devise_for :sellers, :skip => :sessions
  devise_for :buyers, :skip => :sessions
  resources :users
```

**devise/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

**users_controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :name, :type, :email)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer.
Simply need to add value in the form + a condition to check presence of the e-mail param:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, value: params[:email] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Params**

The problem *isn't* to do with STI - it's to do with how you're passing variables / parameters to your form.

You must remember that when you use `form_for`, Rails will automatically populate the provided HTML elements with data from the `ActiveRecord` object - in that if your object has the attribute `email`, the form will have that data populated

If you want to populate the form with *new* data (from a URL), you'll either have to be able to populate the `@user.email` attribute (as suggested by `JTG`), or take the `params` from the URL & pass them through to your form

--

The ways I would look at doing this would include:

> 1. Controller-based (the best)
> 2. Front-end "params" based

The controller method can be accessed as follows:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @user = User.new(email: params[:email])
   end
end
```

This *should* work, as the param should be made available to the controller during the request.

-

The alternative, as you've discovered, is to populate the `value` of the element on your page:

```
<%= f.text_field :email, value: params[:email] %>
```

This will leave the `:email` field blank if no `email` parameter was / is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Making a request to `new#User` (which is what you are requesting with `/buyers/sign_up`) won't  autofill any of the sign_up form by default

However, you can put

```
def new
   @user = User.new
   @user.email = params[:email] if params.has_key? "email"
end
```

for the url

```
/buyers/sign_up?email=abc%40abc.com
```

And it should auto complete the email textfield of your form.

if your url was structured like so...

```
/buyers/sign_up?user[email]=abc%40abc.com
```

Then you should be able to use the much more elegant

```
def new
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
end
```

in your `new` call.  That way you can send in more than one parameter

Comment: Thank you. I added `@user.email = params[:email] if params.has_key? "email"` to the users_controller#new but this does not fill in the field email.
Maybe I should add that the form is in `devise/registrations/new.html.erb`